# Merge and sum values and put them in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

I'm retrieving values from an external source and apply a foreach loop to the results, with the code below.

```
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
    if (value.start_date > firstdayOfWeek && value.start_date < lastdayOfWeek) {
        console.log(value.firstname + ' - ' + value.distance);
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

The result is console for example can be:
kees - 103,4
marco - 44,1
jared - 89,8
kees - 66,2
jef - 23,3
marco - 69,4

I would like to combine all duplicate names and sum the numbers of the duplicates and put them in an array. So the result will be like this for example:
kees - 169,6
marco - 113,5
jared - 89.8
jef - 23.3

What is the best/easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Post your input example, as in the actual data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store `key-value` pair in `array`.

Use [**`object`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to store key-value pair.

See comments inline in the code.

```
var obj = {}; // Initialize the object

angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
    if (value.start_date > firstdayOfWeek && value.start_date < lastdayOfWeek) {
        if (obj[value.firstname]) { // If already exists
            obj[value.firstname] += value.distance; // Add value to previous value
        } else {
            obj[firstname] = value.distance; // Add in object
        }
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
console.log(obj); // Result
```

**Shorter Version**

```
var obj = {}; // Initialize the object

angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
    if (value.start_date > firstdayOfWeek && value.start_date < lastdayOfWeek) {
        obj[value.firstname] = obj[value.firstname] ? obj[value.firstname] + value.distance : obj[value.firstname];
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to use [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

```
 var data = [ {key: "kees", value:103.4},
             {key: "marco", value:44.1},
             {key: "jared", value:89.8},
             {key: "kees", value:66.2},
              {key: "marco", value:69.4},];



var groups = _(data).groupBy('key');

$scope.out = _(groups).map(function(gr, key) {
  return { 
     type: key, 
     val: _(gr).reduce(function(m,x) { 
       return m + x.value;
     }, 0) 
  };
});
```

*Output:*

```
[
  {
    "type": "kees",
    "val": 169.60000000000002
  },
  {
    "type": "marco",
    "val": 113.5
  },
  {
    "type": "jared",
    "val": 89.8
  }
]
```

---

demo in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4pp6zsz/)</kbd>